# PHP forms - link fields together and run function for multiple instances of the linked fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on a form of calculator to calculate the delivery cost for certain items in a company. I've got it working for a single item but I'm currently trying to make it work for multiple items added in the form.

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="quantity">  //Link with below "type"
    <select name="type">      //Link with above "quantity"
        <option value="Grassmat">Grassmat</option>
        <option value="Mesh A">Mesh A</option>
        <option value="Mesh B">Mesh B</option>
        <option value="Mesh C">Mesh C</option>
    </select>

    <div style="display: block;"></div>

    <input type ="text" placeholder="0" name="quantity">   //Link with below "type"
    <select name="type">      //Link with above "quantity"
        <option value="Grassmat">Grassmat</option>
        <option value="Mesh A">Mesh A</option>
        <option value="Mesh B">Mesh B</option>
        <option value="Mesh C">Mesh C</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Postcode Here" name="postcode">
    <select name="location">
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
        <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
        <option value="N. Ireland">N. Ireland</option>
        <option value="Dublin">Dublin</option>
        <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

http://pastebin.com/sRVa0Xyx

The PHP code is large & messy as there are a lot of variables that it needs to pass through.

The outcome I'm hoping to achieve is that when the form is submitted, it runs the PHP for each product added in the form under "type" which needs to have the respective "quantity" linked to it for use in the function.

How do i go about linking the 2 fields and running the PHP on each "type" field using it's respective "quantity" when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

a couple of thoughts
1. check out the array format for name in html: type[] and quantity[] then you can loop through these results easy
2. i would make use of arrays and functions so that this is more of a data config solution vs hard coded if / else style

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was going to clean up the code once I've got the multiple products thing working. I'll give the array format a try with the HTML naming